# I can't see Shadow Demon and Warlock's Golem in DotA

Tags: dota

When I'm playing DotA, I can't see the following heroes/characters:

- Shadow Demon
- Warlock's Golem
- Lucifer
- Crystal Maiden
- Yunero

[image]

If I turn on the shadow, I can see only the shadow. What's going on?  How can I fix this?

Note: Version 1.26a (from 1.25b)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you downloaded the newest map and checked if that works? 6.81d fixed a few more bugs so it might be the case with your bug. [DL Link](http://media.playdota.com/maps/eng/DotA%20v6.81d.w3x) .Have you tried reinstalling Warcraft III already? Did you check if the map is corrupt? Did this problem occur after you downloaded the new map or when?

Comment: I tried switching back to old version using version switcher. Still no change. I tried also different map from different sites, still no luck.

Comment: So even in older dota versions like 6.80 you get this bug? Then it is clearly a bug in wc3 (or your pc) rather than in the mapfile itself. Did you already update your graphic driver? I still would recommend just reinstalling warcraft. That's what I did back in the days if something wasnt working in wc/dota. PS: You should NOT downgrade the wc3 version because the dotamap uses the newest mapeditor entities/etc. Always take the newest version

Comment: All my drivers are correctly installed. And by the way, I'm no average computer user. I am an IT/programmer by profession. So I tried everything to troubleshoot the prob. May be the model for those characters are not loaded or something. Lastly, my system can play Watch Dogs in ultra mode graphics so I think there is no issue regarding my PC specs.

Comment: I just want to know if someone encountered the same problem and found a solution.

Comment: everybodys using rikimaru....

Comment: But dust/gem can't see sh*t.. even on allies.. good point.:)

Comment: I cannot remember, are any of those models modified, or are they base WC3 models? If any are base, do they show up in the campaign, or in any other custom maps?

Comment: I think yes, I tried Moomoo defense and I can't see some shops (at least 2) when I try to buy something. The name is present but the model, health and aura is not. Just like the character shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Do you install from disk or from blizzard?

Comment: I copied from the backup of my old PC.

Comment: Do you still have you CD-Key? Go on battlenet, you can add the CD key to access download of the game, and do a clean install. A "copied" installation is... well... buggy at least whatever your OS.

Comment: At least try to reinstall from CD if you still have it.

Comment: Can I reload just the models at least?. Or some sort? I neither have the CD nor the CD-Key. Thank you.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact the setup doesn t just "copy documents in the right place", but also do a lot of work to ensure the program is complete. You ll need it, a re-copy will not change that. Find someone with a CD-key or buy one, you can find WarCraft III + Frozen Throne for <10€ theses days.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like there are still some textures missing from the game.

Before you try anything else, attempt to run [WarCraft III in OpenGl mode](http://lancraft.blogspot.de/2010/02/how-to-run-warcraft-3-in-opengl-mode.html).

If the problem persists:

1. **Repair** or **reinstall** WarCraft III and The Frozen Throne
2. **Update** to the [newest version](http://www.dota-utilities.com/2011/03/warcraft-126-patch-warcraft-3-tft-v126.html)

Comment: I tried this but still no luck.

Comment: The map version I'm using is Dota 6.81d.

Comment: and warcraft version?

Comment: Note: Warcraft III, Version 1.26a (from 1.25b)

Comment: with frozen throne addon, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. I can't run Dota v6.81d in the first place.

Comment: this oculd take sometime, but try to play the reign of chaos campain (really worth it). jaina proudmoore has the same model as crystal maiden. if you cant see her too there must be a problem with dota.

Answer (score 1):

From what you said in comment, you "installed" WIII from a backup of your old PC.
Windows, sadly, doesn t work like that, and a lot of thing (register for example) might be missing and end up bugging your game by missing textures.

It could also be a simple DRM, setup set a value in the register, needed to decrypt the model. Since you copied the model but don t have the key, the game ignore the model altogether.

What you should do is find your CD, reinstall from it, or if the CD is unusable but you still have a valid CD-key, go on battlenet, and download WIII/Frozen Throne from there and install properly.

If you don t have your CD(-key) anymore, try to find a friend who still have it, or buy one (I find it regulary for 10€ at video games stores, battlenet price seems to be $15).

EDIT:

I ll add that a key for WIII alone seems to give WIII and Frozen throne in battlenet, but I d like confirmation.

Comment: that is what i was saying...reinstall. not recopy ;) but thanks for pointing that out

Comment: since you gave this answer the bounty. did it solve your problem?